# Scheduling and/or Synchronizing HTML5 Video Playback Across Machines

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I'm running 3 different videos with identical durations on 3 separate machines and synchronizing them using a websocket server. I can get pretty accurate time sync between the machines, but changing the `currentTime` attribute of any of the videos results in a significant and unpredictable delay.

In the past with WebAudio, I've been able to schedule playback of an audio source using `start()`, but `video.play()` doesn't have this functionality. And it makes it nearly impossible to say "play this part of the video at this point in time".

Is this not an option with HTML5 video? Is there an out-of-the-box solution I should be trying (e.g. media streams, canvas). I'm using Chrome, but I could easily use another browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there exist no method with Video to sync sources this way.

The problem with setting `currentTime` is that it is an asynchronous operation. When time is set there is no guarantee that the video will play from that time instantly. The browser will check cache, possibly load from the net and decode before the video before it's actually played from that time (and when it does it reports through the `seeked` event).

As long as we miss a form of a *cue* method like in the Web Audio API (which also require data to reside in memory) we are limited in options.

We could maybe get a hackish solution to work at the moment like using two video elements to "double buffer" for the time/positions, when scheduled time is due, start and swap in the second element (which may or may not work depending on system, browser, network, cache, server response time etc.).

Depending on the size and length of the videos you could pre-load image frames instead of video. This would allow for instant sync but at the cost of initial load time and memory.

I believe the more stable solution however would be to sync the streams on *server side* using dedicated solutions and use the browser as a passive client. [VideoLAN](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html) or [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) may do the trick, or some commercial specialized software/hardware related to broadcasting able to handle sync reference signals.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: hey, thanks for a well thought out answer. i thought this might be the case, and i was inspired to hack together a solution by constantly setting `currentTime` until i get the sync result i want. it's hardly perfect, and i'm not sure i'd recommend it to anyone else. but it seems to work. i'll look into the two streaming options you mentioned too.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question that had no solution in 2016 but as of 2022, this can be done by using [MediaSync](http://webtiming.github.io/timingsrc/doc/online_mediasync.html). Just putting it here for someone to find the right path